# Convert httpie post request to python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, httpie

I have difficulties converting a post request using htppie to python requests.post. This question is in general about how to do such a conversion, but I will use the specific request I was doing as an example.

So I have the following post request using httpie, which works fine:

```
http post https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/graphprotocol/graph-network-mainnet query='{ indexers {
                id
               }
}'
```

However, when trying to send the same request using pythons requests library, I tried the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/graphprotocol/graph-network-mainnet'

query = """'{ indexers {
                id
                }
}'"""

print(requests.post(url, data = query).text)
```

This gives a server error (I tried many versions of this, as well as sending a dictionary for the data variable, and they all give the same error). The server error was `GraphQL server error (client error): expected value at line 1 column 1`.

Regardless of what the server error is (which is probably server specific), this at least means that the two requests obviously are not exactly the same.

So how would I go about converting this httpie request to using pythons requests library (or any other python library for that matter)?

Comment: Looks like you've got too many quotes in your Python code. You're including a literal `'` in your Python query, which you're not including when running the shell command.

Comment: i like to use a request inspector to compare things e.g. https://requestbin.net/ make one request from httpie and another from python and compare, then fix the differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass request payload, you need pass json as string (I used `json.dumps()` for conversion). To pass body as form-data, pass just dict.

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/graphprotocol/graph-network-mainnet'

payload=json.dumps({'query': '{indexers {id}}'})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

**Note.** I recommend that you try to make this request in Postman and then you can convert the code to Python right in Postman.

Comment: In your case, you can skip headers section.